# Coffeescript Regex interpolation

Tags: coffeescript

Coffeescript supports strings interpolation:

```
user = "world"
greeting = "Hello #{user}!"
```

Is it possible to use interpolation in regex just like in strings? E.g.

```
regex = /Hello #{user}/g
```

P.S. I know that I can use `RegExp(greeting, 'g')`, I just want a bit cleaner code.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Block Regular Expressions (Heregexes) support interpolation.

> ### Block Regular Expressions
>
> Similar to block strings and comments,
>   CoffeeScript supports block regexes — extended regular expressions
>   that ignore internal whitespace and **can contain comments and
>   interpolation**. Modeled after Perl's /x modifier, CoffeeScript's block
>   regexes are delimited by /// and go a long way towards making complex
>   regular expressions readable.

This coffeescript code:

```
name="hello"
test=///#{name}///
```

compiles to

```
var name, test;

name = "hello";

test = RegExp("" + name);
```