# Matching Hubot's name in Coffeescript

Tags: regex, coffeescript, hubot

I want to create a Hubot script which listens for strings that look like:

```
thanks Hubot
```

where `Hubot` is the bots name.  If we assume that bot is always named `hubot`, then it's trivial:

```
robot.hear /thanks hubot/i, (msg) -> 
    ...
```

But the name of course can vary, though is contained in the `robot.name` variable.

Question: how do you interpolate the bot's name into the regular expression?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631638/coffeescript-regex-interpolation) seems to indicate you can just use block regular expressions, but I tried:

```
robot.hear ///thanks #{robot.name}///i, (msg) ->
    ....
```

And it didn't seem to work.

Edit: I have a workaround, I can extract the second word and compare to the bot's name, like so:

```
  robot.hear /thanks (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    name = msg.match[1]
    if name.toLowerCase() is robot.name.toLowerCase()
      ....
```

But this feels rather kludgy, I'd like to be able to just interpolate a variable into the regex itself.

Comment: Our hubot has a script like this: https://github.com/sukima/river-song/blob/master/scripts/thanks.coffee

Comment: What was the error because `robot.hear ///thanks\s+#{robot.name}///i, (msg) ->` [works for me](https://github.com/sukima/river-song/blob/master/scripts/thanks.coffee#L35).

Comment: You linked to something different than what you say works.

Comment: @Sukima: NICE!  Really like the addition of emoji, so I'll use your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `///`s in Coffeescript don't just allow interpolation, they engage the full extended mode which means that whitespace is no longer significant inside those regexes, ie. if you want to match a space then you have to use something like `\s`

So try this:

```
robot.hear /// thanks \s+ #{robot.name} ///i
```